# Incorporating both changes when resolving git merge confilct

Tags: git, git-merge

Let's say we have 2 development branches (`master` and `feature`) and  both branches added some code to the same file. When trying to merge `feature` into `master` we run into a single confict:

```
++<<<<<<< HEAD
+ //some code added in master branch
++=======
+ //some code added in feature branch
++>>>>>>> feature
```

If I want to accept only `HEAD` (master) and abandon `feature` I would run:

```
git checkout --ours path/to/file
```

If I want to accept only `feature` (master) and abandon `HEAD` I would run:

```
git checkout --theirs path/to/file
```

How can I accept both changes so that the result of the conflict resolution would be as simple union of the code?

```
//some code added in master branch
//some code added in feature branch
```

Comment: I don't think there is a safe way to do automatic merges in this scenario.  In many places, the order of the added chunks would matter, and in many scenarios, changes in one will affect the other.  If you can resolve your particular scenario with little or no manual editing, good for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nevik pointed, a simple removal of markers would result in the union of the code.
Here's my bash script that does the job:

```
function git.both() {
  filename=$1
  tempfilename="temp_file_used_by_git_both"
  grep -v "<<<<<<<\|>>>>>>>\|=======" $filename > $tempfilename
  mv $tempfilename $filename

}
```

Usage:

```
git.both path/to/file
```

Comment: If you want to make this super-helpful for other users, you could add a short note about integrating it with git via aliasing ;)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to edit the file manually, and remove the conflict markers (if you only do that, the result is exactly the "union" you want).

Git will not do this because conflict resolution is a semantic problem to which a program cannot offer a general solution.

Though if you do this often or on a large scale, you could doubtless write a script for it (doing this in an automated way is likely to break your code though).

Comment: You are right, removing the markers would do the job in my case. If there's no git such command, then I will right a simple bash script